# Django - SuspiciousOperation, request session deleted

Tags: python, django, session

I'm getting this error and I have no idea why:

```
SuspiciousOperation at /file/path/

The request's session was deleted before the request completed. 
The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.
```

I know the user isn't logging out (no account to log in to in the first place).

The error is occurring in one of my views when I make a call to `request.session` and try to pull some chart data that I have stored. It's causing my charts to not display on the page since it can't pull the data in time.

Here is the stack trace:

```
/opt/name/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
131.   response = middleware_method(request, response)

/opt/name/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py in process_response
61.    "The request's session was deleted before the "
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

EDIT - In the code where the error is occurring:::

```
def exmaple_function(request, name):
    response = request.session['key']['key'][name]
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="text")
```

What's interesting is that these errors only happen on my production version of the site - not my local testing or sandbox versions.

Comment: You haven't show us the code for the view in question.

Comment: Edited my original post. Left it out because I don't think the problem is with the code in the view as it works perfectly in my local testing and sandbox versions of the site - just not the production version of the site.